# Display element only when 2 properties in an object match

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the first render the object comes like this

```
{
  behindPosition: null,
  chipBet: undefined,
  chipSelectedId: null,
  mainPosition: 4,
  sitBehind: (),
  submitbetBehind: bound componentDidUpdate(),
  timer: false
}
```

as you see almost every prop is `null` or `undefined`

now there is a button in the view

```
<button id={`playerBehind${position}`}
        onClick={this._enclosingFunctions}>Bet Behind</button>
```

once you click on that button, the object changes by adding more props, so:

```
{
    behindPosition: 4,
    mainPosition: 1,
    chipSelectedId: null,
    timer: true,
    nickname: "omega",
    refPosition: 4,
    balance: 10000,
    action: "",
    onGame: true,
    betAmount: 0,
    simpleBetAmount: 0,
    message: "",
    lastBet: 0,
    buttons: [],
    position: 1
}
```

I recorded a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDPM1jUVYug&feature=youtu.be) because we are using socket.io so you the error will be reproduced in the right browser within the video.

As you see there is a `Bet Behind` button in both views, once you click in the button on the left screen, the same button its been rendered in every spot of the right screen, which shouldn't be happening. I need that button to keep displayed only the spot where you saw it at the beginning of the video. The prop `behindPosition` is the position that you take once you click on the button.

So, all I need is to see that button in the spots where `mainPosition` is the same as `refPosition`, which is not happening now, the app is not taking into account anything of that, it is just rendering the buttons in every single spot. By spots I mean the white circles in the view which are 7. So there could be 7 `mainPosition`, and the button, again, should be displayed only when `mainPosition` is the matches `refPosition`

Now, here the way I have my code:

```
class BetBehindSpot extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    'sitBehind'       : React.PropTypes.func,
    'behindPosition'  : React.PropTypes.number,
    'mainPosition'    : React.PropTypes.number,// position of the spot owner (main player)
    'refPosition'     : React.PropTypes.number,
  }

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render () {
    console.log('on render', this.props);
    const position = this.props.mainPosition;
    const behindPosition = this.props.behindPosition;
    let displayButton;
    if (behindPosition) {
      document.getElementById(`betbehind-spot${behindPosition}`).style.display = 'block';
    } else if (behindPosition !== position) {
      displayButton = (
        <button id={`playerBehind${position}`}
             className="betbehind-button" onClick={this._enclosingFunctions}>
          <span>Bet Behind</span>
        </button>
      );
    } else {
      displayButton = null;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {displayButton}
      </div>
    );
  }

  _enclosingFunctions = () => {
    this._sitBehind();
  }

  _sitBehind = () => {
    if (!this.props.refPosition) {
      this.props.sitBehind();
    }
  }
}
```

so, what are your recommendations ?

Comment: im struggling to really see what you're trying to achieve here. A component might return null in the render method if the props is not set yet, but i'm not really sure if thats what you're looking for

Comment: Any chance you can clarify your question, and ideally, make it generic? Are you just asking about object comparison?

Comment: There is a lot of code/properties in this question that are not relevant to the issue. You should boil this down to the simplest possible case, to help people understand your issue